# how can i creating window station and windows desktop using c#

Tags: c#, windows, process, desktop

i would like create new window station &  windows desktop and attach my process to it. how can i do that

i need to know

1. Creating Window station and attach my desktop
2. Creating & switching between Desktop effectively
3. how do i attaching process to winlogon desktop(if it is possible )
4. Destroy created desktop and return back to windows desktop

Comment: This article will help in combination with p/invoke: http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops

Comment: WebAchive for Brian's link  https://web.archive.org/web/20130317092805/http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops

Answer (score 4):

There is only one interactive window station per 'session' but you can have multiple sessions.

http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2010/02/24/3315174.aspx

I'm not aware of an API to directly create a login session but if you are using a Windows Server version you could use Remote Desktop to create a local session, autorun your program there, then logout again once the program has ended (the program you are running in the Remote Desktop Session could logout when finished).

The code below will use the MSTSC ActiveX control to programmatically create an RDP session.  You will need to manually generate the ActiveX stubs and add them to your project.

1. From the Visual Studio Command Prompt type the following:

   ```
   aximp.exe %windir%\system32\mstscax.dll
   ```
2. Copy the generated files (MSTSCLib.dll and AxMSTSCLib.dll) to the project directory.
3. Add both files to the project references.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AxMSTSCLib;
using MSTSCLib;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

namespace AutoLogin
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient5 rdpClient;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            rdpClient = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient5();
            ((ISupportInitialize)rdpClient).BeginInit();
            rdpClient.Enabled = true;
            rdpClient.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            rdpClient.Name = "MsRdpClient";
            rdpClient.Size = ClientSize;
            rdpClient.TabIndex = 1;
            rdpClient.Anchor = (AnchorStyles)
                (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom |
                 AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
            Controls.Add(rdpClient);
            ((ISupportInitialize)rdpClient).EndInit();
        }

`void axRemoteDesktop_OnDisconnected
        (object sender, IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent e)
    {
        Application.Idle += ExitTimerEvent;
    }

    public void ExitTimerEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Idle -= ExitTimerEvent;
        // Attempt to close down the session we just connected to (there
        // appears to be no way to get the session id, so we just close all
        // disconnected sessions.
        if (rdpClient.Connected == 1) {
            rdpClient.Disconnect();
        }
        LogoffDisconnectedSessions();
        Close();
    }

    private Timer logoffTimer;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close down any existing disconnected sessions, the number of
        // available sessions is limited.
        LogoffDisconnectedSessions();

        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        rdpClient.Server = "localhost";
        rdpClient.UserName = username;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = password;
        rdpClient.Domain = "";
        rdpClient.FullScreen = false;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectDrives = false;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectPrinters = false;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectPorts = false;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings2.RedirectSmartCards = false;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings6.RedirectClipboard = false;
        rdpClient.AdvancedSettings6.MinutesToIdleTimeout = 1;

        rdpClient.OnDisconnected += new 
            AxMSTSCLib.IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEventHandler
                (axRemoteDesktop_OnDisconnected);

        rdpClient.Connect();

        logoffTimer = new Timer();
        logoffTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(LogoutTimerEvent);
        logoffTimer.Interval = 150000;
        logoffTimer.Start();
    }

    private void Form1_Close(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Idle -= ExitTimerEvent;
        if (rdpClient.Connected == 1) {
            rdpClient.Disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void LogoutTimerEvent(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        logoffTimer.Stop();
        rdpClient.Disconnect();
    }

    enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
        public int SessionId;
        public string pWinStationName;
        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WTSLogoffSession(IntPtr hServer, int SessionId, bool bWait);
    private static IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool WTSEnumerateSessions(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            int Reserved,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            int Version,
            ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
            ref int pCount);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

    private void LogoffDisconnectedSessions()
    {
        IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
        int count = 0;
        if (WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1,
                                 ref buffer, ref count)) {
            WTS_SESSION_INFO sessionInfo = new WTS_SESSION_INFO();

            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                sessionInfo = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                   new IntPtr(buffer.ToInt32() +
                              (Marshal.SizeOf(sessionInfo) * index)),
                   typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

                WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS state = sessionInfo.State;
                if (state == WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSDisconnected)
                {
                    WTSLogoffSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE,
                                     sessionInfo.SessionId, true);
                }
            }
        }
        WTSFreeMemory(buffer);
    }
}`

}

Answer (score 0):

Although Windows supports multiple "window stations", the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687096(VS.85).aspx) states that:

> The *interactive window station*, Winsta0, is the only window station that can display a user interface or receive user input. It is assigned to the logon session of the interactive user, and contains the keyboard, mouse, and display device. All other window stations are noninteractive, which means they cannot display a user interface or receive user input.

This indicates that the ability to switch between window stations in the way you are proposing is not possible.